# Http request does not complete

Tags: csv, http, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get data from a csv file on the internet:
https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv

If you clicked on it you might have noticed that it downloads automatically, which I think is the problem.

When I'm using the [http library](https://pub.dev/packages/http) in dart to get this data, I only get back a small part of it at the beginning. The `response.statusCode` is still equal to `200` and everything else works as expected.

I think that the automatic download is part of the problem but I'm not sure how to fix that

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
...
main(){
  String url = 'https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  print(response.body);
}
```

Comment: FYI, it depends on the browser - Chrome downloads it, while Safari opens in the tab

Comment: it should be downloading the file, `response.bodyAsBytes` will a have a Uint8 list containing the file as bytes, write to a file using `File` class, or use http.readBytes(url)

Comment: `print` always truncates long strings. You probably have the whole csv in memory but are only seeing the first bit because of that truncation. Try `print(response.body.length)` to prove that.

Comment: @mangusta Ok, so I guess that's not the problem

Comment: @RichardHeap yeah I checked the length and it actually did give me the complete data. Silly mistake from my part I guess. I come from python where I was easily able to print long strings such as these.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with json format:

```
  Future<Response> fetchData() async
  {
   return await http.get("https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json");
  }
```

Then inside the `build()` method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: fetchData(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Response> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                Map<String, dynamic> map =
                    Map.from(jsonDecode(snapshot.data.body));
                return Text(map["LBN"]["continent"]);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        ));
  }
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but I found out the actual problem was that dart doesn't print everything when you tell it too.

Comment: yes thats the reason, it is giving the data but its better to use futurebuilder to make sure that its working